# CSS Animation sudden move

Tags: html, css

I have the following JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ur9bpgbn/163/

```css
.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: #FFF;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 999;
}

.arrow.active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.arrow.active.animate-left-to-right {
  animation-name: move-left-to-right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternative;
}

.arrow.active.animate-right-to-left {
  animation-name: move-right-to-left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternative;
}

@keyframes move-left-to-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX (5%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(15%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(5%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
}

@keyframes move-right-to-left {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-5%);
    box-shadow: -3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-15%);
    box-shadow: -3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-5%);
    box-shadow: -3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
}


/*right arrow*/

.arrow-right {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7));
}

.arrow-right:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.arrow-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}


/*left arrow*/

.arrow-left {
  border-radius: 0 0px 0px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7));
}

.arrow-left:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.arrow-left:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: -20px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid #FFF;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <a href="https://sporedev.ro" target="_blank">
    <div href="#" class="arrow arrow-right animate-right-to-left">This is a text</div>
  </a>
  <div href="#" class="arrow arrow-left animate-left-to-right" style="margin-top:30%; margin-left:30%;"><span class="room-desc">This is a text</span></div>
</div>
```

The arrow that moves to the right side works perfectly.

The arrow to the left side has some kind of a glitch, it has a sudden move when it reaches the end of the transition.

I tried applying changes to the CSS in everything related to the left arrow with no effect. The script has some JS that adds the "active" class and I tried removing it to simplify the script and make sure it's not a JS related problem with no effect.

Tried reading up transitions but I didn't found any solutions. I'm sure that I miss something that is CSS related.

How can I make the arrow that points to the left side move smoothly?

Comment: FYI: `animation-direction: alternative` - they correct keyword name is `alternate`, not alternative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update this part `transform: translateX (5%);` to `transform: translateX (0%);`

```
@keyframes move-left-to-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX (0%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(15%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
    box-shadow: 3px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ur9bpgbn/168/

I believe the little jump is the 0-5% which it is not animating so it just jumps

Comment: I think that was the only part that I didn't touched when I tried resolving the problem. It works like a charm. Will accept the answer in 3 minutes. Thank you!